# Java format datetime from "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm trying convert datetime from format `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`.
It work well, but sometime still error.
Example: from `"14/07/2020 17:46:32"` -> convert result `"2188-04-14T17:32:32.000Z"`, and i don't know why ?
Can someone please explain to me. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is incomplete for stackoverflow. Can you please put how your code looks like only then people can help.

Comment: Sorry not able to understand properly. What you do mean by sometimes?

Comment: That sounds like `SimpleDateFormat`! A notorious troublemaker of a class. And long outdated. I recommend you don’t use it. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter`, `ZoneOffset` and `OffsetDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I am sure we can help! When you show us your faulty code and tell us the expected result.

Comment: Not sure it’s exactly what you want: `LocalDateTime.parse("14/07/2020 17:46:32", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString()` yields `2020-07-14T17:46:32Z`.

Comment: This is my code: 

private static String getTransTime() {
 String time1 = "14/07/2020 17:46:32";
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTime(df.parse(time1));

 SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
 String time2= fmt.format(calendar.getTime());
 return time2;
}

Comment: I have singleton Class process http request, in this class has method getTransTime(). Class process and get time correct in almost request, sometimes incorrect. ex: "14/07/2020 17:46:32" -> "2188-04-14T17:32:32.000Z".